# Why is my program only going into a function some of the time when there are no conditionals involved?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, function, module, controller

I'm fairly new to Angularjs and I am struggling to figure this problem out on my own.  I'm looking through the tutorial [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module), but I cannot find where I'm going wrong.  I have a module like so:

```
var myMod = angular.module( "modTest", [ 'angular-counter', 'ngDialog' ] );
myMod.factory( "myService", [ "$http", "$log", myService ] )
    .controller( "myCtrl", [ "$myvar", myCtrl] );
console.log("test 1");
```

And then I have a control defining a function higher up in the code as follows:

```
myCtrl = function( $myVar )
{
    console.log("test 2");
}
```

From what I understand, when I do the myMod.controller it should *"run"* the function I have described above and print "test 2" to the console.  I have the first code block running on every page, and "test 1" does indeed get printed to the console on every page.

However, on a couple of pages, "test 1" gets printed but not "test 2".  When I use Chrome dev tools to try to debug the issue, I find that I always hit a breakpoint on the line `myCtrl = function( $myVar )`, but I don't always go into the function which is causing the problem.

I have never encountered a problem like this before, and I'm quite baffled as to why it's happening.  If I inspect the myMod variable after it is created and after the .factory and .controller are run, I find that in both cases its gets filled up properly (i.e. it's not nulling out or anything like that as far as I can tell.)

Can someone tell me what steps I can take to try to get into myCtrl every time.  Or, in other words, how to get "test 2" to print on every page?

Comment: Create a demo that replicates problem. Hard to assess without seeing how controller gets assigned to view. Also not clear where `$myVar` comes from. My guess is you haven't used `ng-controller` or set router to assign the controller so it never gets called

Answer (score 0):

```
var app = angular.module('modTest', []);
app.service('myService',[])

.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', myCtrl]);

function myCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
}
```

use this code which helps you, when you declare myCtrl as above which myCtrl is not defined.
Note: never used $for user defined variables.